Does the following series converge? To which value?
Given $f(x)=A \cdot x^5+B \cdot x^8$
with:

$A \in \mathbb{R}^-$
$B \in \mathbb{R}^-$
$h(z) = w_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty h_n \cdot \frac{\left(z-f(w_0)\right)^n}{n!}$
$w_0=1$

and:
$$h_n=\lim_{w \rightarrow w_0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}} \left[\left(\frac{w-w_0}{f(w) - f(w_0)}\right)^n\right]$$
i.e.
$$h_n =\lim_{w \rightarrow 1} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}} \left[\left(\frac{w-1}{A \cdot (w^5-1)+B \cdot (w^8-1)}\right)^n\right]$$
Does $h(z)$ converge?
What can be said of $h(-C)^2$ with $C \in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Your question is answered here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial

$R^-$ is the negative reals?

@GerryMyerson yes, updated to use \mathbb{R} instead.

@MartinNicholson where? I do not see anything relating to the convergence
